# How to solve this rank-deficient linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Basically, I have a very simple system of linear equations of the form $Ax = b$, namely,

$$  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
     1 & -1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}e_1 \\ e_2 \\ e_3\end{bmatrix} $$

so obviously matrix $A$ is rank-deficient; but we can apply an additional condition by letting:

$$ p_1 = 0 $$

and we also guarantee that:

$$ e_1 + e_2 + e_3 = 0 $$

then the linear system is solvable now. We are going to solve it with scientific computing packages like NumPy or Eigen, but all these packages solve this problem with the syntax:

```
Solve(A, b) ==> return x
```

Is there any scientific computing package allowing me to apply the additional condition ($p_1=0$, in my case), so the problem can be solved like:

```
Solve(A, b, conditions on x) ==> return x
```

Or is there any way to re-arrange the equation by eliminating $p_1$ from $x$, as $p_1$ is constant to be zero?

Comment: If you want $p_1 = 0$, then this corresponds to the system $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p_2 \\ p_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ e_2 \\ -e_1 - e_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Nothing more to say.

Comment: To answer the mode general question, if the conditions on $x$ are linear equality constraints (such as $p_1=0$), then most packages will expect you to rewrite them yourself as part of $A$ and $b$. On the other hand, if they are inequality constraints, or convex constraints, then you could use a package for solving convex optimization problems. However, using those to solve a linear system will likely result a less accurate solution since the numerical properties of linear solvers are highly optimized.

Comment: For example, you could use `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` and solve $\min_p\|Ap-b\|$ subject to $0\leq p_1 \leq 0$, but in general using a  least squares algorithm for a linear system is a great idea.

Comment: The system was solvable before you introduced the additional conditions. It just didn’t have a _unique_ solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.

Our real problem is of course much more complicated, and we've adopted the [Normal Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html) to solve it.

First we re-arrange our problem by eliminating *p1* (a little different from Theo Bendit's way, bc in real problem we cannot assume e3=-(e1+e2) ):

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 \\
    1 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}p_2 \\ p_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}e_1-(-1 \cdot p_1) \\ e_2-(1\cdot p_1) \\ e_3-(0\cdot p_1)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}e_1 \\ e_2 \\ e_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

let's simply annotate the new equation like:

$$
Mp = e
$$

Then we do:

$$
M^T Mp = Lp = M^T e = e'
$$

then the problem can be easily handled in Numpy:

```
Solve(L, e') ==> return p values
```